Extend linear regression over the whole plot
I have a set of data and I want to perform a linear regression on them and display the resulting line.
Due to computational precision, the values reach a plateau after a certain point, and I don't want to include these data in the computation of the regression.
What I'm currently doing is having two data files: one with all the data, and another with the data used for the sole linear regression (maybe not the best, but I did not find anything else). Here is an MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{data.dat}
h err
0.05 3.11604689111e-09
0.025 1.89857594659e-11
0.0125 3.14299545014e-13
0.00625 2.38864314351e-14
0.003125 4.93001614302e-14
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{data_for_reg.dat}
h err
0.05 3.11604689111e-09
0.025 1.89857594659e-11
0.0125 3.14299545014e-13
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmode=log, ymode=log]
\addplot[only marks,blue] table[x=h,y=err]{data.dat};
\addplot[no markers,red,thick] table [x=h,y={create col/linear regression={y=err}}] {data_for_reg.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Resulting in a figure with all data (in blue) and the linear regression on the points selected, but only on them (in red):

What I'd like to do is extend this line to the whole plot, as displayed in green in the Figure above (the green has been manually added on the screenshot)

First, pgfmath is rather inaccurate.  If possible, precompute the linear regression using another language or a smart calculator.  BTW, there are three different types of linear regression: fit y to x, fit x to y, and fit both ($\sum (y-y_i)^2+(x-x_i)^2$)

From the pgfplots manual (section 4.24 Fitting Lines – Regression), the  parameters of the regression are stored into \pgfplotstableregressiona and \pgfplotstableregressionb. So draw the corresponding function, with an appropriate domain and the key update limits=false to keep yours axes unmodified:
\addplot[update limits=false, no markers, green, thick, domain={1e-3:1e-1}]
{x^\pgfplotstableregressiona*exp(\pgfplotstableregressionb)};

Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{data.dat}
h err
0.05 3.11604689111e-09
0.025 1.89857594659e-11
0.0125 3.14299545014e-13
0.00625 2.38864314351e-14
0.003125 4.93001614302e-14
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{data_for_reg.dat}
h err
0.05 3.11604689111e-09
0.025 1.89857594659e-11
0.0125 3.14299545014e-13
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmode=log, ymode=log]
\addplot[only marks,blue] table[x=h,y=err]{data.dat};
\addplot+[no markers, white] table [x=h,y={create col/linear regression={y=err}}] {data_for_reg.dat};
\addplot[update limits=false, no markers, green, thick, domain={1e-3:1e-1}]
{x^\pgfplotstableregressiona*exp(\pgfplotstableregressionb)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



that was simple ! Thanks for the answer !
